# Transforming a square into a parallelogram

Tags: matrices, transformation

as an exercise I wanted to calculate the transformation matrix in order to make the square $ABCD$ into the parallelogram $A'B'C'D'$. I am able to get the matrix so that the square is first at the center $(0,0)$ and rotate it there that $A$ is at the same place as $A'$. But then I need to make the square to into a parallelogram.
How can I calculate this matrix?
The square at $(0,0)$ has coordinates from $-1.5$ to $1.5$.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgevv.png)

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is a translation $T$ and a projection $P$.

You can determine the terms of $P$ by looking at $P(B-A)$.

Each unit step in $x$ gives $1/3$ of $B' - A'$, so the first column is $(-1/3, -2/3)$.

Similar for $P(C-B)$ we find that the second column of $P$ is $(1, 0)$.

The rest is just a translation vector, which you can determine from $T = P(A)- A' = (-6, 2)$

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient if you add to the component $x$, for example, some dependence on the $y$ component. Let's say if you matrix is something like
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & a \\
0 & 1 \end{array}

then, the $y$ component of your square will remain the same, but the $x$ will be shifted $\pm 1.5a$, depending if it is the upper side or the lower one of the square.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine do it in several steps, i.e. multiple transformation matrix multiply together. Not showing matrix as I don't know whether you know *Homogeneous Coordinates* for better matrix multiplication.

1. Translate the original square to be centered at origin. $(-7.5, -3.5)$
2. Rotate the square 90 degrees so that $A$ is on the top left hand corner
3. Scale up x direction $4.5/3$
4. Scale down y direction $2/3$
5. Apply x direction *shear* transformation (described in seoanes's answer)
6. Translate again to the final position. $(-6, -2.5)$

Comment: Isn't it easier to move $A$ and $A'$ to the origin and then transform the basis given bij $AB$ and $AD$ to one given by $A'B'$ and $A'D'$?

Comment: @HSN I just think it's easier to imagine the process, so that reduce the error rate.

Comment: matrix multiplication